# Debug an system application

Tags: android, debugging, adb, system, root

I'm trying to develop an app that requires System App permission (for example, I want to reboot the device and install new apks).
Now, I write the code and I generate a apk which I place intro /system/priv-app.

Then I reboot the device and I run the app.

The problem is that I want to debug my app, because write code without debugging is so tedious.

Can be debugged a system app?

And how?

The device is rooted, so I can do anything with it, and, for the release version, it will be a full image of AOSP with the apk contained in /sytem/priv-app

Regards.

Comment: There are many ways actually how can you do that..
1. You can create your own log file, or make some kind of admin tool inside app, and request that tool. 
2. Store all debug to sq lite db for 24 hours and then delete, free memory.
3. Output any output to server or email ( but app should be connected to the internet)

Comment: OK I will try that.